# Get random row based on a few tag values in a table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to use this query to get a random row based on `top_tag_id`.

Problem is that it always return `top_tag_id`  as **1**

```
SELECT  Name,top_tag_id,Ranked FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY top_tag_id ORDER BY rand()) as seqnum from books) a where seqnum=1 limit 1
```

my `books` table contains INT top_tag_id's and could have duplicate top_tag_id's

How do i return a random `top_tag_id` at each execution of the query?

Comment: Please verify my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use MySQL RAND() function.

```
SELECT  Name, top_tag_id, Ranked, RAND() as seq
FROM books
ORDER BY seq
LIMIT 1;
```